# Unable to locate package coturn | Debian 10

Tags: server, debian, apt, package-management

I have a fresh server with debian 10.3.

I want to use it as a STUN/TURN server for webrtc.

But I have already issues with step one. Installing coturn.

Every single guide tells me:

```
On Debian and Ubuntu there are official repository packages available: sudo apt install coturn
```

I also tried:

```
apt install coturn 

apt-get install coturn
```

Eventhough all guides tell me there are official packages available, it seems that its simply wrong.
I searched manually for a package and found:

https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/coturn

Now I am worried. Shall I search for a method to install it manually or am I missing something?

I have not much experience with debian and linux in general.

This is what I see after I try to install it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package coturn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you have a freshly installed Ubuntu system, the cache is empty. 
>   This is why you should run the apt update command right after
>   installing Ubuntu or any other distributions based on Ubuntu

Just run `sudo apt update` or `apt update` and it should work. Did for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

I looked it up on the debian repository and it should be available for arm32.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBL5L.png) 
What CPU architecture do you use? Mine is "armv7l" (raspberry pi 4).
It is possible that the package is not available for your current architecture.
the link https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/coturn that you provided states that this package runs on i386 (32bit intel/amd) amd64 (64bit intel/amd) armel and armhf (32 bit arm). Could it be that you are using a 64bit arm processor with 64 bit debian?
to find out which processor type you have type `uname -m` in a terminal.

### possible solutions in no particular order

- install 32 bit debian instead of 64 bit (it should still work on a 64 bit processor)
- see whether the package is distributed as an appimage / snap / flatpak
- look up how to compile it from source

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the answer. I havent tested your solution, because I already switched to ubuntu. I had a 64bit processor an i7.

Comment: Okay. I have the exact same problem on ubuntu 19. Will try your solutions now